# $.ajax Post method giving error while sending special characters in email body

Tags: jquery

I am using `$.ajax` POST method in MVC 2.

There are two texboxes for sending email (Subject, Body).

Our tester is putting below string for negative testing.

`^&%@#&*(^!*^#*(!@^#)(!@*#_())(*&^%$&*^*&^*&#&*(^!`

And we are getting below error

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client >(email_subject="...^%$&*^*&^*&#&*(^").

[image: image of error]

Can you please us know how can we resolve it using encoding or any suitable solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to avoid this error, try decorating the controller action you are posting to with the `[ValidateInput(false)]` or `[HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]` attribute.

You can remove the validation on a specific field of your action by using:

```
[HttpPost, ValidateInput(true, Exclude = "YourFieldName")]
```

FYI the attributes of your query string are validated when you submit and special characters create this error. Be careful when using this trick: if your application is for public use, you may use an other solution.

Comment: Hi Nicolas, 
There is breakpoint on that CONTROLLER, but it is not hitting while I am sending negative string in subject or in body.

Comment: This solution works for me. What can be best solution for this ?
So that everything works fine without any worry ?
:)

Comment: I Used [HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)] because [HttpPost, ValidateInput(true, Exclude = "YourFieldName")] did not work because of "Exclude"

Comment: OK I edited the response ;) I personaly used [ValidationInput(false)] for the same problem yesterday but filtering the validation on only some fields could be better.
For the best solution, it will depend on your method/page functionality: see an example here of risks SQL injection about http://www.troyhunt.com/2012/12/stored-procedures-and-orms-wont-save.html

Comment: Ok , Thanks Nicoloas for providing the link.